# Loop em intervalo de hora

Tags: java, datetime, iterator

Preciso percorrer um intervalo de hora para montar uma grade com horários. Exemplo: intervalo 08:00 as 10:00, adicionando 30 minutos.
Formando uma grade assim:
08:00
08:30
09:00
09:30
10:00

Estou tentando assim:

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    Date hInicial = null, hFinal = null;

    try {
        hInicial = sdf.parse("08:00");
        hFinal = sdf.parse("10:00");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GregorianCalendar inicio = new GregorianCalendar();
    inicio.setTime(hInicial);
    GregorianCalendar fim = new GregorianCalendar();
    fim.setTime(hFinal);

    gc.setTime(hInicial);
    while(!inicio.after(fim)) {

        gc.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

    }
```

O sistema fica em loop infinito.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está testando se a variável `inicio` está depois de `fim` e dentro do `while` você não modifica nenhuma das duas variáveis. Tente utilizar `inicio` ao invés de `gc`. Ficando assim:

```
while(!inicio.after(fim)) {

    inicio.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você nunca altera o estado de `inicio` e nem de `fim` no corpo do seu `while`, então o valor de `inicio.after(fim)` nunca vai mudar, causando o loop infinito.